# 'values' is only available in iOS 15.0 or newer in Combine

Tags: swift, async-await, combine

Can we bring down Combine `values` to iOS 14? (Currently, it supports only iOS 15), so we can bridge Combine to asyn/await. For example

```swift
let publisher = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  .publisher
  .delay(for: .seconds(3), scheduler: RunLoop.main)
  .eraseToAnyPublisher()

for await value in publisher.values {
  print(Date())
  print(value)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Playground with an implementation of a custom bridge between a publisher and an `AsyncSequence` as well as an extension, `myValues`, for `AnyPublisher`.

It behaves similarly to Apple's `values` async publisher though I can't promise that it behaves properly in all the same concurrent context's that Apple's will work in.

```
import UIKit
import Combine
import PlaygroundSupport

struct MyAsyncPublisher<P> : AsyncSequence where P : Publisher, P.Failure == Never  {
    typealias Element = P.Output
    typealias AsyncIterator = AsyncStream<P.Output>.AsyncIterator

    var upstream : AnyPublisher<P.Output, Never>
    
    init(_ upstream: AnyPublisher<P.Output, Never>) {
        self.upstream = upstream
    }

    func makeAsyncIterator() -> AsyncStream<Element>.AsyncIterator {
        var subscription : Subscription?

        let stream = AsyncStream<Element> { continuation in
            let mySubscriber = AnySubscriber<Element, Never>(
                receiveSubscription: { s in subscription = s; s.request(.max(1)) },
                receiveValue: { continuation.yield($0); return .max(1) },
                receiveCompletion:  { _ in continuation.finish(); subscription?.cancel() })
            
            self.upstream.receive(subscriber: mySubscriber)
        }
        
        return stream.makeAsyncIterator()
    }
}

extension AnyPublisher where Failure == Never {
    var myValues : MyAsyncPublisher<Self> {
        MyAsyncPublisher<Self>(self)
    }
}


func doIt() async {
    let publisher = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
      .publisher
      .delay(for: .seconds(3), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
      .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
      .eraseToAnyPublisher()

    for await value in publisher.myValues {
      print(Date())
      print(value)
    }
}

Task {
    await doIt()
}

PlaygroundSupport.PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```